# How to create a step-by-step cumulation of data?

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

Probably my question is really dull but I couldn't find an easy solution for that. So we have a data.frame **without** (overall) column. Overall column must present a cumulative  number of pies (in my case) eaten up to a certain time period. What is the easiest way to create it in R for an infinite number of rows? Thanks!

```
  Year Pies eaten Pies eaten(overall)
1 1960 3          3
2 1961 2          5
3 1962 5          10
4 1963 1          11
5 1964 7          18
6 1965 4          22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cumsum`

```
df1$Pies_eaten_Overall <- cumsum(df1$Pies_eaten)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought cumsum command returns just an overall number for the whole row...but good to know!